# Why is filter & includes returning an empty array in the case below?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does the code snippet below return an empty array despite 'Delhi' being included in both arrays?

```js
const cities = [
  { _id: '5bqAPcRutbZDgfdRT', name: 'Ahmedabad' },
  { _id: 'PSzMrGENYKfF2wbKQ', name: 'Anand' },
  { _id: 'tJZnaQuiy8bvvmv3B', name: 'Bangalore' },
  { _id: 'SFuvn99mtn5qgZrXh', name: 'Delhi' },
  { _id: 'SKFibyqad3sfqs3N2', name: 'Goa' },
  { _id: 'wLP4whAeYnaqDeZt7', name: 'Kolkata' },
  { _id: 'Hv8L7cw8Mn6m8uMXv', name: 'Lonavala' },
  { _id: 'vbc4RJjPq5xMGizbS', name: 'Mumbai' },
  { _id: 'uHaqkBZQqTEEhW4yv', name: 'Pune' },
  { _id: 'jfBaJf3ssqaX8zzx4', name: 'Surat' },
  { _id: 'pdcnk5jLPigh24iBe', name: 'Udvada' },
  { _id: '5EEZCdgN8zbBs5gKP', name: 'Vadodara' }
]

const addressSplits = [ ' India', ' Haryana', ' Delhi', 'DLF Place' ]

const city = cities.filter((el) => addressSplits.includes(el.name));

console.log(city);
```

Output: `Array[]` instaed of `Array[{ _id: 'SFuvn99mtn5qgZrXh', name: 'Delhi' }]`

Comment: Because `'Delhi' !== ' Delhi'`. There is a leading space in most of your `addressSplits` values.

Comment: OMG!!!! How did I miss this? I've been staring at this for 45 minutes now haha. Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leading space in the addressSplit array. My bad guys. Thanks @CherryDT